# Minecraft Blockdata. Cannot Put A Specific Spawn Egg in A Chest (Minecraft 1.10.2)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to put a specific spawn egg in a chest using blockdata for a project I'm doing. I'm trying to put a blaze spawn egg with enchants, and a custom name. I know the data value for a blaze is 61, however when I put this command in and press the button the chest has a white spawn egg that spawns nothing. Anyone know how to fix this?

Here's my command:

```
/blockdata ~ ~1 ~ {Items:[{id:spawn_egg,Count:1,Damage:61}]}
```

Also, can anyone figure out how to add a custom name and enchant? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 1.9, spawn eggs use the `EntityTag` compound to specify the entity's name ID, rather than the `Damage` value of the item.

All tags for items that are not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, and `Slot` must be placed within a single `tag` compound.

The following provides a blaze spawn egg enchanted with Sharpness 3, and with a custom display name.

```
/blockdata ~ ~1 ~ {Items:[{id:"minecraft:spawn_egg",Count:1,tag:{EntityTag:{id:"Blaze"},ench:[{id:16s,lvl:3s}],display:{Name:"Custom Name"}}}]}
```

You can find all item NBT data [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure).

Comment: Thanks! It Worked! By the way, do you know how to name the item as well? I need a named item for it to work in my project Im doing. Thanks.

Comment: @Cobalt772 Sure, added to the command.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks! It Worked! By the way, do you know how to name the item, and specify which slot that item will be in as well? I need a named item for it to work in my project Im doing. Thanks!